# How to specify DNS server for a VPN connection by PowerShell without first being connected to the VPN?

Tags: windows, powershell, vpn

I am a newbie at PowerShell but wouldn't ask without spending a ton of time looking online first.

Is there any possible way of specifying ipv4 DNS Server (and alternate) without being connected to the VPN first?

I am installing VPN profile for a business which I can do manually but there is close to 180 users which I am trying to implement through a PowerShell script in Endpoint Configuration Manager. I am obviously trying to work smarter, not harder.

I already have the Add-VpnConnection script down which works great but I still have to manually change the Primary and Alternate DNS for ipv4.

In addition, I would like to turn off ipv6 for this VPN but  that coincides with this originally problem I am running across.

Any help or ideas down the right path would be much appreciated!

Comment: Both the DNS Server and ipv6 settings apply to the vpn interface and not the vpn profile. That interface doesn't exist while the VPN is disconnected, so you can't edit settings for it (but I'm not sure that's true for all vpn types). Normally, you should set this in your VPN host's dhcp settings instead. You can verify with `Get-NetIPInterface -InterfaceAlias 'VPN Name'` before and after connecting to the VPN.

Comment: ConfigMgr (the tool you're going to use to deploy these settings) natively supports basically every VPN client under the sun.  Have you taken a look at its native VPN Profile Distribution support?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/protect/deploy-use/vpn-profiles

Comment: @Cpt.Whale thank you for the info. I am going to look into this later when I get some free time.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale That's the official info, but if you view network adapters via the Windows GUI you can see the VPN adapters even while disconnected, and you can set the DNS servers here... again, while disconnected. And there are VPN services that don't let you control this via DHCP.